# How to Allow multiple spaces in between the text using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, pattern-matching

I have the following regex:

```
^([A-Za-z0-9\._-]+ )+[A-Za-z0-9\._-]+$|^[A-Za-z0-9\._-]+$
```

This allows alphanumeric characters, dots, underscores, and hyphens. I want the regex also to allow multiple spaces in between. How do I do this?

Comment: Is this what you want? https://regex101.com/r/H8fgx2/1

Answer (score 0):

use

1. `\s+`
2. `[ ]+`
3. `[ ]{2,3}` if you need exclude 1 space

```js
string = string.match(^([A-Za-z0-9\._-]+ )+\s+[A-Za-z0-9\._-]+$|^[A-Za-z0-9\._-]+$);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want:

- to allow only alphanumeric chars, dots and hyphens in words
- 1+ spaces are allowed between words, but not leading and trailing spaces

Here is a solution that allows multiple spaces ( `+` instead of  ), and simplifies the word regex to `[\w\.-]+` from `[A-Za-z0-9\._-]+` since `\w` contains `[A-Za-z0-9_]+`:

```js
[
  'all-allowed.chars',
  'one space',
  'two  space',
  ' leading space',
  'trailing space ',
  'off-limits:!@#$%^&*()_+'
].forEach(str => {
  let result = /^([\w\.-]+ +)+[\w\.-]+$|^[\w\.-]+$/.test(str);
  console.log(str, ' => ', result);
});
```

Output:

```
all-allowed.chars  =>  true
one space  =>  true
two  space  =>  true
 leading space  =>  false
trailing space   =>  false
off-limits:!@#$%^&*()_+  =>  false
```